# Do these options affect other modules and possibly core?

Tags: 8, composer

I have a question about downloading an unstable version of a module using composer. I run `composer require 'drupal/page_manager:^4.0'` but I get this error message.

> The requested package drupal/page_manager ~4.0 is satisfiable by drupal/page_manager[4.x-dev, 4.0.0-beta3, 4.0.0-beta2, 4.0.0-beta1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

I looked at the repository, and they don't seem to have a stable version. So I read that in my composer.json file I should put the following lines.

```
"prefer-stable" : true,
"minimum-stability": dev,
```

If I set these options to composer, will this affect other modules and possibly Drupal core? when I update core, could it download a development snapshot higher than the current version? If so, how do I downloading the development snapshot only for a module without affecting other modules/core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fine to set `minimum-stability` to `dev`. [Error: Conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability](https://www.drupal.org/project/address/issues/2820284) describes it is there by default.

You can set `minimum-stability` because `prefer-stable` prefers stable packages over unstable.

Answer (score 2):

[See prefer stable's documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#prefer-stable)

> When this is enabled, Composer will prefer more stable packages over unstable ones when finding compatible stable packages is possible. If you require a dev version or only alphas are available for a package, those will still be selected granted that the minimum-stability allows for it.

[See minimum-stability's documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability)

> This defines the default behavior for filtering packages by stability. This defaults to stable, so if you rely on a dev package, you should specify it in your file to avoid surprises.
>
> All versions of each package are checked for stability, and those that are less stable than the minimum-stability setting will be ignored when resolving your project dependencies. (Note that you can also specify stability requirements on a per-package basis using stability flags in the version constraints that you specify in a require block (see package links for more details).
>
> Available options (in order of stability) are dev, alpha, beta, RC, and stable.

These will do exactly as they sound, they will prefer a stable release, if there is one that satisfies your composer requirements, otherwise they'll look to unstable releases that are at least in "dev".